# Issue in Angular route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have an AngularJS application. I recently added couple of routes but they don't work. The rest is working fine.

I included them in my index.html

```
    <script src="privacy_policy/privacy_policy.js"></script>
    <script src="contacts/contacts.js"></script>
```

I added them in my app.js file:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    ...
    'myApp.privacy_policy',
    'myApp.contacts',
    ...
]).
```

The route system:

```
$routeProvider.when('/privacy_policy', {
    templateurl: 'privacy_policy/privacy_policy.html',
    data: {
        needauth: false
    }
});
$routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
    templateurl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
    data: {
        needauth: false
    }
});
```

I added a simple controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module(
    'myApp.privacy_policy', ['ngRoute']
).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
}]).
controller('PrivacyPolicyCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "store", "URL", function($scope, $http, store, URL) {
}]);
```

And some simple html:

```
<div ng-controller="PrivacyPolicyCtrl" class='row below-header'>
    PRIVACY POLICY
</div>
```

Finally I created a simple link to that view:

```
<li><a href='/privacy_policy'>Privacy policy</a></li>
```

I created the SAME things for contacts but if I click on those link ng-view is completely empty.
All the others route are working fine and I can't see any difference. I get no error on the console.

In the route system in app.js If I put a different template, for example:

```
$routeProvider.when('/privacy_policy', {
    templateurl: 'faq/faq.html',
    data: {
        needauth: false
    }
});
```

The faq page is diplayed correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: What is an error ?? have you make html in contact view?

Comment: There is no error, simply when I go to myapp.com/contacts or myapp.com/privacy_policy The page is empty a part from the basic layout. The content of ng-view is empty. I have made the same html for contact and for privacy_policy, I didn't paste both of them because they are basically the same only with different controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally find you what the problem is.

I only needed to change this:

```
templateurl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
```

with this:

```
templateUrl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
```